# pst-pulley produce big red dots

Tags: pstricks

Based on [the document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-pulley/pst-pulley-doc.pdf) I use the [`pst-pulley`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-pulley) package by XeLaTeX in TeX Live 2013, but (without grid) produces the big red dots.

[image: output]

What is wrong?

Here the codes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.7in,paperwidth=8.3in,bindingoffset=0in,left=0.8in,right=0.8in,
top=0.7in,bottom=1in,headsep=.5\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-pulley}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1cm}

\section*{Contoh 3}
\begin{center}
\pspulleys[N=3,M=60,h=25]
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

After using `\listfiles` at first line, I get as follow and the big red dots are still there.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./cobi4.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9h> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-def/xetex.def)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def)) (./pst-pulley.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)
`PSTricks' v2.49b  <2013/12/21> (tvz)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xetex-pstricks/pstricks.con
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/config/xdvipdfmx.cfg
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-pulley/pst-pulley.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-grad/pst-grad.tex
`pst-grad' v1.06, 2006/11/27 (tvz,dg,hv))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-slpe/pst-slpe.tex
 v1.31, 2011/10/25)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-eucl/pst-eucl.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.30, 2013/09/17) (c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
  v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>)
`PST-Euclide v1.48, 2013/05/02 (Dominique RODRIGUEZ)
 This version uses the pst-xkey package for managing parameters
 Please read the doc, some macros have a new syntax
 use option old for upward compatibility)
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks-add/pstricks-add.tex
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-plot/pst-plot.tex
 v1.57, 2013/12/01 (tvz,hv))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-3d/pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-math/pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.62 , (CJ,hv)) `pstricks-add' v3.63, 2013/12/14 (dr,hv))
 v0.01, 2012/01/17(ts)  v0.01, 2012/01/17))
(c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/pst-xkey.sty) (./cobi4.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: xetex
[1] (./cobi4.aux)
```

Comment: In miktex and xelatex, it works fine.

Comment: Use `\listfiles` as first line in the example report the file versions (listed at the end of the document). It should be no problem with TL2013.

Comment: Thank you all, the problem has been solved with updates via Package Manager\tlmgr\Load net default repository: http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your TeX distro to avoid this red dot issue. It is known issue in a certain package.

Compare your version with mine as follows.

[image]

```
\listfiles% to recheck your package version
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20mm,12pt,svgnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-pulley}
\begin{document}
\pspulleys[N=3,M=60,h=25]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have downloaded the distro: TeXLive-20130530-bin.tar.xz (here ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2013/). How do I install it on Windows 8.1?